# react router does not render when the url changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have the following in `Main` component;

```js
<Routes>
    <Route path="/forum/*" element={<Forum />} />
</Routes>
```

and this inside `Forum` component

```js
<Routes>
    <Route path=":topicName" element={<QuestionFeed />} />
</Routes>
```

When I first navigate to `/forum/programming`, the router renders as expected. But after clicking on a `Link` only the URL updates and the component does not re-render.

`<Link to="programming">`

**Why does the router not render when clicking on a Link but renders if I visit the url manually.** ?

```
"react":            "^17.0.2",
"react-dom":        "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
```

Comment: Hi, your issue can be illustrate by a codepen/stackbiz. It will help you to clarify the problem. Anw, your code looks good, I think the issue is not come from react-route, it might related to hooks/your components lifecycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

The problem was in `QuestionFeed` component.
The state was only being updated in `useEffect` that only executed once since the dependency array was empty. Added the url parameter to the list to have it update the state.

```
    const { topicName } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        setQuestions(questions || []);
        ...
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, []); // empty dependency array
```

```
    const { topicName } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        setQuestions(questions || []);
        ...
    }, [topicName]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to try with full url /forums/programming.

Answer (score -1):

Inside the `Forum` component you will have to specify the parent route url also. You can get the parent url from the `match` props inside the `Forum` component, then you can do

```
<Routes>
  <Route path={`${parentRoute.url}/:topicName`} element={<QuestionFeed />} />
</Routes>
```

Or in your case this should also work

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/forum/:topicName" element={<QuestionFeed />} />
</Routes>
```

Basically you have to specify the full path for `path` in `Route`

Then you can use the link component like `<Link to="/forum/programming">` and it should work